# Application(class) is not accessible from java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a helper class and added something in my `Application` class that I wanted to use in my helper class. I'm accessing my `Application` class like this.

```
myApp = ((MyApp)ctx.getApplicationContext());
appName = myApp.getInstance().getQueue();
```

When I run my app, I always get this error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: void [packageName].MyApp.<init>() is not accessible from 
java.lang.Class<android.app.Instrumentation>
```

Even after I commented out every declaration of `MyApp`, I still get that error. I think I might be doing something wrong but I don't know what it is.

Is there a better way of doing what I want?

Comment: "Even after I commented out every declaration of `MyApp`, I still get that error." – That error would be happening when the system tries to instantiate the class that you've specified as the `android:name` on the `<application>` element in your manifest. If you still want to use it, make sure that it's `public`, and that it has a `public`, no-parameter constructor. If you're trying to remove it, then get rid of that  `android:name` attribute on the `<application>`.

Comment: @MikeM. I don't know why I did it but I made my `Application` constructor `private`. Thanks man.